# Get video url and path

Tags: typo3

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZboZ.png)

On the screenshot you can see information which I have. I need to get url and path for this file. It's avideo. I use TYPO3 7.6.16

Comment: you can get it using:
`$obj->getVideo()->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile()->getPublicUrl()`

Comment: Please post it as answer, so you get the reputation for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the path of the video using the below code:

**Extbase:**

```
$obj->getVideo()->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile()->‌​getPublicUrl();
```

**Fluid:**

```
{obj.video.originalResource.publicUrl}
```

Comment: So I can't do it in the fluid template ? I mean get public url

Comment: For the fluid you need to add `{obj.video.originalResource.publicUrl}`

Comment: which object is it? cObject. I am asking because i have the same issue.

Comment: @webfacer It is object of the class model having FAL property `video`. Its not the `cObject`. For example OP has model `Istar\Fefiles\Domain\Model\Video` and its property `video` check OP's screenshot.